# Importar articulos en Prestashop desde un XML

Tags: php, prestashop

Tengo una tienda de venta de equipo de computo y quiero incluir los productos de un proveedor en mis articulos. El proveedor me proporcionó un xml el cual importare con PHP. Puedo leerlo sin problema pero me interesa saber que tablas son las que tengo que afectar para que los productos se puedan visualizar en mi tienda.

Answer (score 0):

Justamente hace poco he desarrollado un sistema de importación a través de CSV. Te sugiero que te olvides de tablas y uses el objeto Product. Él se encargará de tocar las tablas que le haga falta.

Para ello simplemente recorre el XML, extrae los datos de cada producto y ve rellenando los campos del objeto Product. Cuando acabes con un producto hace $product->add() y a por otro.

Answer (score 0):

quiza esto te pueda ayudar a aligerar tiempo, es una solución ya hecha con la que solo tienes que adaptar la primera configuración.
https://www.alabazweb.com/es/modulos-prestashop-importadores-exportadores/368-modulo-importador-feeds.html

ESpero que te sea de utiliad
saludos